# i have valid provisioning profile, but still Application is not getting installed on iPhone Device

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile

I have a valid provisioning profile installed.
but i am getting some Lexical or preproccesor issue as:

```
CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h file not found.
```

when try to install app on device.
it is working fine in simulator.

Could you please help me, what could be the issue?

Comment: Make CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h optional instead of Required and try to run the app.

Comment: Clean your project. Select Project from navigator panel, under targets -> build settings -> search path -> framework search paths, set your framework search path = $(inherited) as non-recursive and $(SRCROOT) as recursive. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you re-check if you have linked the coreGraphics library in Linked Libraries? Also which device are you trying to use?

Comment: Yes , Libraray Framework exists
i have tried to remove and then add again framework.
It is happening For all the projects.